# .NET Angular using RequireJS

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, npm, requirejs, google-distancematrix-api

I created a new ASP.NET Empty Web Application in Visual Studios 2013. I have an angular project with the following directory structure:

```
├───TestProject
│   ├───index.html
│   ├───package.json
│   ├───Web.config
│   ├───app
│   │   ├───app.module.js
│   │   ├───main.js
│   ├───bin
│   ├───node_modules
│   │   ├───google-distance
│   │   │   └───test
│   │   ├───json-stringify-safe
│   │   │   └───test
│   │   ├───qs
│   │   ├───request
│   │   │   └───lib
│   ├───obj
│   │   └───Debug
│   │       └───TempPE
│   ├───Properties
│   └───Scripts
└───packages
    ├───angularjs.1.6.1
    │   └───content
    │       └───Scripts
    │           └───i18n
    │               └───ngLocale
    ├───AngularJS.Core.1.6.1
    │   └───content
    │       └───Scripts
    └───RequireJS.2.3.2
        └───content
            └───Scripts
```

Here's what my `packages.json` looks like:

```
{
  "name": "google-distance",
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "main": "index",
  "description": "A simple node.js wrapper for Google's Distance Matrix API",
  "author": {
    "name": "Edward Look",
    "email": "edwlook@gmail.com",
    "url": "http://edwardlook.com"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/edwlook/node-google-distance.git"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "google",
    "maps",
    "distance",
    "matrix",
    "api"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "google-distance": "~1.0.1"
  }
}
```

I ran `npm install` and it created the node_modules folder. At the top of my `main.js` file I have:

```
var distance = require('../node_modules/google-distance/index.js');
```

But every time I load the page the console says:

```
require.js:168 Uncaught Error: Module name "../node_modules/google-distance/index.js" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded
    at makeError (require.js:168)
    at Object.localRequire [as require] (require.js:1433)
    at requirejs (require.js:1794)
    at main.js:2
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I use the google-distance module?

Comment: If you want to use that API from an Angular app, why not use an Angular wrapper like this: https://github.com/nausica/angular-google-distance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you should require it as follows;

```
var distance = require('google-distance');
```

The way node will look for modules is as follows;
It will perform a hierarchical directory search for "node_modules" and "google-distance" in the following ways:

- ./node_modules/google-distance.js
- ./node_modules/google-distance/index.js
- ./node_modules/google-distance/package.json

Also, it looks like you should use the asynchronous callback version of require to load this library.

```
require(['google-distance'], function (distance) {
    //package is now loaded.
});
```

From the require FAQ:

> MODULE NAME ... HAS NOT BEEN LOADED YET FOR CONTEXT: ... This occurs
>   when there is a require('name') call, but the 'name' module has not
>   been loaded yet. If the error message includes Use require([]), then
>   it was a top-level require call (not a require call inside a define()
>   call) that should be using the async, callback version of require to
>   load the code.

http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded